# ESP8266 Arduino. Problem with 128K virtual memory via external SPI SRAM

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I have got internet radio project based on ESP8266 and VS1053 board - https://github.com/h1aji/Esp-radio/blob/dev/src/main.cpp
(I enable SPIRAM when compile the project. // gets removed from line 45)

I am trying to add external SPI RAM 23LC1024 for buffering using this code:

```
#define SPIRAM
  #if defined ( SPIRAM )
    ESP.setExternalHeap();                             // Set external memory to use
    ringbuf = (uint8_t *) malloc ( RINGBFSIZ ) ;       // Create ring buffer
    dbgprint ( "External buffer: Address %p, free %d\n", 
                    ringbuf, ESP.getFreeHeap() ) ;
    ESP.resetHeap();
  #else
    ringbuf = (uint8_t *) malloc ( RINGBFSIZ ) ;       // Create ring buffer
  #endif
```

And I see nothing, buffer is empty. Log:

```
D: Connected to server
D: Switch to HEADER
D: No data input
D: Trying other station/file...
D: STOP requested
D: Stopping client
-----
D: Connect to new host n0e.radiojar.com/hcrb063nn3quv?rj-ttl=5&rj-tok=AAABfwB-IbEAy4LwSrywI0a45Q
D: Connect to n0e.radiojar.com on port 80, extension /hcrb063nn3quv?rj-ttl=5&rj-tok=AAABfwB-IbEAy4LwSr
D: Connected to server
D: Switch to HEADER
D: content-type: audio/mpeg
D: audio/mpeg seen.
D: icy-name: -
D: icy-metaint: 16000
D: Switch to DATA, bitrate is 0, metaint is 16000
D: First chunk:
D: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
D: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
D: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
D: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

The test sketch from https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/esp8266/examples/virtualmem/virtualmem.ino works just fine as well as SPI RAM test code in the beginning.

What am I missing?

Comment: Is `SPIRAM` defined?

Comment: @romkey yes, I enable it when compile the project.

Comment: What do you means "I enable SPIRAM when compile the project"? Obviously if the conditional block is missing, it means that you probably don't have `#define SPIRAM` anywhere in your code.

Comment: What if you just remove the `#if defined ( SPIRAM )` line and the entire `#else .. #endif` block?

Comment: @hcheung seriously? It means that I remove // from line 45 when i compile the code.

Comment: @hcheung I wouldnt be asking here if it was simple like this

Comment: @Murad we have no idea what you know. Also nobody is going to look at your Github repo. Actually I just did and you do have the `#define` commented out. So it is an entirely reasonable assumption that you compiled this without it defined and that's why you're having this problem. If you want help don't get snarky at people who are trying to help.

Comment: @romkey I dont have problems when I have commented SPIRAM, thats why its commented in the repo. the problem appears when I compile with ESP.setExternalHeap(); nothing gets written in the buffer. I didnt see any help yet. Someone just says that i dont have #define SPIRAM anywhere in the code, I didnt expect that silly replies here. Thats why I added more info